# Why take over the galaxy?

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, space-travel, space-colonization

Assuming that interstellar travel is possible but quite slow (slower than light) and expensive (in energy and resources) and that faster than light communication is not possible, what could motivate a sentient species to try to conquer its home galaxy, by mean of self-replicating von Neumann machines or generation spaceships (rather than investing these resources in its home system).

Comment: I think the idea of being both able to make such swarms from systems itself and having construction costly are inherently at odds with each other. There is enough matter in a system to make multiple dyson spheres, production of resources shouldn't be an issue at that tech level.

Comment: why not to change constrains? One of the problem is you haven't decided for yourself what means a star system conquest, what it gives. Leaving the practical benefits of such expansion undefined, you end-up with irrational reasons, which are plentiful in numbers.

Comment: There's a problem with this question that I believe needs to be addressed. As of this writing, there are two answers that each list three very different, valid reasons, as well as a comment that identifies a seventh. Again, these are _all_ valid reasons in the current context of the question. Please provide objective criteria so the community that identify one answer as better than another. If you do, I will gladly retract my close vote.

Comment: If you have to tell people not to post lists of answers in answers, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is technologically and economically possible to conquer the galaxy, someone will do it, even if it is just by accident of free running Von Neumann mechs. So: why conquer the galaxy? So that you aren't ruled by or killed off by someone else. It is the same reason corporations, cities, and nations tend to grow until all available resources are claimed, and then they pause for a while while they use their internal resources. Then they go to war when one of them runs out of resources and cannot trade for more (or slightly before they run out).

Existence is a zero-sum game at every scale. We have a lot of good ideas about sharing resources equally, but that just means that all parties will sunset at the same time. If one party wants to outlive the others, they have to pull resources somehow. If the others aren't feeling self-sacrificial... war.

Answer (score 4):

1. Rare and scattered resources.  The rare element Unobtanium-5 is only found in certain star systems controlled by another faction, while your vast stores of Unobtanium-2 are guarded closely and coveted by many.
2. Ideology.  Some races may feel it's their destiny, others may be paranoid or xenophobic.
3. Greed  They payoff is eventually going to be worth it.  If you build into the game mechanics, a multiplicative effect for owning more star systems, such as increased diplomatic power in trade negotiations and/or production, this would motivate them.

Comment: Also part of the cause of some Earth empires expansion was keeping the military employed so that powerful generals have something to occupy themselves with instead of home politics.

Comment: It isn't greed to want to survive. If the elements your race needs to live are exhausted on homeworld, you'll have to harvest them from elsewhere, even at the cost of another species' survival and/or expansion, or voluntarily die.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Richard U and Kilisi's answers, there are some other possibilities:

- To combat population boredom/restlessness (post-scarcity society)
- Extreme population growth (extremely high birth rate with low mortality rate and long lifespan)
- As a political move to create artificial scarcity and maintain control over a population (Orwell's *1984* style)

I'm sure there are others, but those are all viable.

Answer (score 1):

Go the Rick & Morty route, have an omnipotent force from outside the galaxy impose rules upon those within it, for their own entertainment. It's already a game, why not game-ify the world of those within? If you can't think of a valid justification for your game logic, invoke a higher power.

[image]

Show me what you got!